# Count query works too slow in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am using couchbase:community-6.0.0 in my Spring application. I have like 250.000 records in database. My database query works very fast without using COUNT query command.

```
SELECT app.*, META(app).id AS id FROM app WHERE ( deleted = FALSE OR 
deleted IS MISSING ) AND _class = 
“com.myexample.app.device.data.model.DeviceEntity” AND appId = 
“something” AND dp.language = “somelanguage” LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

This query works very well and fast…Response time smaller than 50ms.

However

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM app WHERE ( deleted = FALSE OR deleted 
IS MISSING ) AND _class = 
“com.myexample.app.device.data.model.DeviceEntity” AND appId = 
“something”
```

It takes 1 minute. I can not reduce.

Indexes

## primary

CREATE INDEX `class_appId_idx` ON `app`(`_class`,`appId`)

CREATE INDEX `ix1` ON `app`(`_class`,`appId`,ifmissing(`deleted`, false))

What is the solution of this ? I think index does not work with a count ? Any advice please, how can I achieve this?

Note : I tried with EE edition, did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The system isn't able to match the index to the query. Sometimes the optimizer isn't all that bright. Try this:

```
create index ix_test on test(_class, appId) WHERE deleted = FALSE OR deleted IS MISSING
```

That will use the index.

Generally speaking, because of how we build the indexes, we have trouble with IS MISSING clauses. But putting that bit in the WHERE clause of the index makes it work. But this is a very specialized index. Consider changing your data so the "deleted" field is always present.

Comment: It did not work actually, I dropped my old index and used your command. Nothing changed at all. My query was 

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM app 
    WHERE ((`deleted` = false) or (`deleted` is missing))
    AND _class = "com.myexample.appconnect.device.data.model.DeviceEntity" 
    AND `appId` = "something"; 

:/ I actually deleted all index including primary.

Comment: Did you change the FROM clause from "test" to "app"? If not, I can only say there must be some subtle difference between my version of couchbase and yours. In that case I suggest you consider changing your data model so "deleted" is always present. That will make the query more straightforward and the indexing simpler.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to rewrite your query like this `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM test WHERE IFMISSING(deleted, false) = false AND _class = 
"com.myexample.app.device.data.model.DeviceEntity" AND appId = 
"something"` and use an index like this: `create index ix_test_im on test(_class, appId, IFMISSING(deleted, false))`

Comment: I changed test to app mate. Thank you for advice. It even does not make sense to me why response time lasts around 1 minute. It tells me in after IndexScan3 step, in FETCH, loses like 45-50 second. However, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have tried your last queries, it takes much better. 26.63s rather than 1 minute. Still need to reduce :/

Answer (score 0):

It works in miliseconds with using enterprise-6.0.0